# Is there a way to use the inner class at the same declare it?

Tags: java, class

I know the following way works:

```
package mypackage;

public class Main{
    public void oFunc(){
        class Inner{
           void foo(){

           }
        };
        Inner s = new Inner();
        s.foo();
    }
}
```

Is there a way something like this could create the object and at the same time declare it?
This could not be compiled, is there a similar way to do this?

```
package mypackage;

public class Main{
    public void oFunc(){
        new class Inner{
           void foo(){

           }
        }().foo();

    }
}
```

Comment: If you could explain what you are trying to do with this code, maybe there is a better way of implementing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With an anonymous class, you could do

```
new Object(){
    void foo(){
    }
}.foo();
```

but that is the only place you'll be able to use any of the members declared inside the class body.

Answer (score 1):

You can have it like anonymous class as follow:

```
 public class Main{
    public void oFunc(){
      new Object(){
       void foo(){
       }
     }.foo(); 
   }
 }
```